# Бывает ли такой цикл?

Tags: php, циклы

$a=rand(0,5)x7; // должен сгенерить 7 случайных чисел от 0 до 5

Просто не хочу FOR писать, рука устает.

Comment: Смени руку.. )   Такой конструкции нет, но чем `for` не угодил?

    for($i=0;$i<7;$i++) $a=rand(0,5);

Comment: работает, но много лишнего.

Comment: Это что, попытка угадать синтаксис? Это приводит к мысли, что новоиспеченные программисты php считают что метод проб и ошибок гораздо эффективнее чтения учебников ))

Comment: Может, пока еще не поздно, Вы обратите внимание на python? 
>>> [random.randrange(0,5) for x in range(0,7)]
[4, 0, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4]

Comment: Вам точно стоит на питон обратить вниманием. Кстати, еще в python'е можно так:

    >>> 'a' * 7
    'aaaaaaa'

    >>> (7,) * 7
    (7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7)

Comment: не слушайте их, оставайтесь на php)))))

Comment: Да на питоне можно много чего интересного придумать. К примеру, генератор написать:

    def randlist(min, max):
        while True: yield randrange(min, max)

Comment: Я такой вопрос закрыл бы.

Comment: Это признаки артрита. 
Может стоит заказать индивидуальную клавиатуру, с кожаными подставками для запястий?

Comment: а в Ruby еще интереснее:

7.times {..}

Comment: Странно что array_map никто еще не использовал

Comment: Просто ради интереса как это происходит в Рубях:

7.times.ma­p{Random.r­and(20)}

Красота не правда ли ?

Answer (score 6):

```
$i=0;while($i<7)$a[$i++]=rand(0,5);
```

Короткого варианта нет.

**Добавлено 27.09**

```
$i=7;while($i--)$a[$i]=rand(0,5);
```

Просто ради фана можно сэкономить пару символов.

Comment: можно еще 2 символа сэкономить :)
    $i=7;while($i--)$a[]=rand(0,5);

Comment: Точняк. =)

Comment: Можно еще короче с шансом 1 к 6, что зависнет :)  
 
    while(!$a[6])$a[]=rand(0,5);
а вот если убрать нулевое значение, то всегда все ок:  

    while(!$a[6])$a[]=rand(1,5);

Answer (score 4):

```
function random_array($count, $start = null, $end = null) {
    for (; $count; $count--) $result[] = rand($start, $end);
    return $result;
}

random_array(7, 0, 5);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = array_map(function($v){return rand(0,5);},range(0,6));
```

Comment: Все портит вызов функции, а так более менее классно.